# Printing out a vector produces different results every time. It also prints random code that isn't in the vector

Tags: c++, xcode

So I am reading in a file of zeros and ones.

```
1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0
1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0
1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0
1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0
1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0
1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0
1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0
```

I read in this file and store it into a 2d vector. I then print this 2D vector and get these results as output.

```
\311[\240\3778\311[\240\377P\311[\240\377h\311[\240\377\200\311[\240\377\230\311[\240\377\260\311[\240\377\310\311[\240\377\340\311[\240\377\370\311[\240\377\312[\240\377(\312[\240\377@\312[\240\377X\312[\240\377p\312[\240\377\210\312[\240\377\240\312[\240\377\270\312[\240\377\320\312[\240\377\350\312[\240\377\313[\240\377\313[\240\3770\313[\240\377H\313[\240\377`\313[\240\377x\313[\240\377\220\313[\240\377\250\313[\240\377\300\313[\240\377\330\313[\240\377\360\313[\240\377\314[\240\377 \314[\240\3778\314[\240\377P\314[\240\377h\314[\240\3771110+2+,0,+a_0co0%We0Enab1AK1ages1eKey0r_1ons_1rvic0_000069631Ap1SUse1co0PKSe1NSLi1e_0"NSA0led_1tion1NSPr1DMSE0ging0mptD0ionE1sDat0appl1A_001D6961y_0mati0$NSA0able1nEna0sRequested_Microsoft Controller_#NSAutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled\Dell S2830dn_AppleMiniaturizeOnDoubleClickQ1           \2410Uen-US3A\300\274\265\302\317+w\32134VdirMap\320    U10.14\241:\323;<=>?@WreplaceTwithRonSomwZOn my way!"?\2003A\300\321i\245z% XMaximizeUen_US\321GH_NSWebServicesProviderW,\200\306IJKL_qDisplayName_NSProviderIdentifierVGoogle^com.google.www   3A\300\321j
\273\375    3A\300\320Sa.$p\245RSTUV_0~/Desktop/CompSci 2100/2100Project3/2100Project3_ ~/Desktop/CompSci 2100/Project_2_~/Desktop/CompSci 2100_#~/Desktop/CompSci 2110/2210project2_0~/Desktop/CompSci 2110/2210Project3/2210Project3#?\340TDark           \244]E^_RenRtrRfr   _{\233\303\333\361 =_s\221\300\333\3709Y}\232\277\322\355\371*Hc\206\241\265\3223Z\201\244\306\335023457=FIPQRTZ\^emruy\204\206\213\224\225\236\244\247\310\315\344\373%+^\201\232\300\363\374  binput1.txt
\377\377\377\377\377q\205<оa\310\214 CPX@\360dCFPreferencesMessages\340@
\360\200CFPreferencesShmemName\220apple.cfprefs.501v1CFPreferencesShmemIndex0\364CFPreferencesShmemState@\360\200CFPreferencesShmemName\220apple.cfprefs.501v1CFPreferencesShmemIndex0\245CFPreferencesShmemState@\360\200CFPreferencesShmemName\220apple.cfprefs.501v1CFPreferencesShmemIndex0\343CFPreferencesShmemState@\360\200CFPreferencesShmemName\220apple.cfprefs.501v1CFPreferencesShmemIndex0YCFPreferencesShmemState@\360TCFPreferencesShmemName\220apple.cfprefs.501v1CFPreferencesPropertyList\200\255bplist00\337    

234_com.apple.trackpad.version_.com.apple.trackpad.fourFingerHorizSwipeGesture_.com.apple.trackpad.fourFingerPinchSwipeGesture_.com.apple.trackpad.fiveFingerPinchSwipeGesture_com.apple.mouse.tapBehavior_ com.apple.trackpad.rotateGesture_com.apple.ColorSync.Devices_'com.apple.trackpad.enableSecondaryClick_com.apple.trackpad.pinchGesture_!com.apple.trackpad.scrollBehavior_5com.apple.trackpad.twoFingerFromRightEdgeSwipeGesture_)com.apple.trackpad.threeFingerDragGesture_(com.apple.trackpad.threeFingerTapGesture_/com.apple.trackpad.threeFingerHorizSwipeGesture_-com.apple.trackpad.fourFingerVertSwipeGesture_.com.apple.trackpad.threeFingerVertSwipeGesture_#PKSecureElementAvailableFlagsByHost_!com.apple.trackpad.momentumScroll_,com.apple.trackpad.twoFingerDoubleTapGesture  \322+_0Device.cmra.63306330-3362-6536-3839-633063343435_0Device.mntr.C07EE717-D5E0-4933-131D-70E3DC02779B\322!_DeviceDescriptions_FactoryProfiles\321 Uen_USViPhone\322"#$*Y555810816_DeviceDefaultProfileID\322%&')_DeviceModeDescriptions_DeviceProfileURL\321(WDefault_[/System/Library/Frameworks/ICADevices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Camera RGB Profile.iccY555810816\321,-^CustomProfiles\321./Q1_:/System/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/Generic RGB
```

it is actually a lot more than this but I think that would be too much for a question. It prints stuff like this sometimes only one sentence long sometimes forever. I have never experienced something like this I am just trying to print a 2D vector I have done this 1,000's of times with no problems. I am using xCode and here is my code for the whole project.

```
//read in the file into a double vector

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;



class OBJs{

public:
    string Obj;
    int numItemsInObj; 
};

//vector to store all of the data for the grid and the row of the big vector
vector<OBJs> row;
vector<vector<OBJs>> grid;

//maybe create an object for the found parameters
OBJs tempObj;


//functions
void load(string fileName);
void printObjs();


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    string file;

    cout << "Please enter your filename here: ";
    cin >> file;
    load(file);


    printObjs();


    return 0;
}


void load(string fileName){
    //read in a line and insert the line(string) into the second index of the vector
    string line;
    string zeroOrOne;
    ifstream file;

    file.open(fileName);
    //basically a guard let function in swift
    if(!file){
        cout << "Could not open the file " << fileName << endl;
        //exit(0);
    }
    // you have successfully entered the file specified
    while(getline(file, line)){
        //grabbing each line of the file into the var line
        //delimit this line by , in getline
        istringstream ss(line);
        while(getline(ss, zeroOrOne, ',')){
            //put it into the row vector.
            tempObj.Obj = zeroOrOne;
            tempObj.numItemsInObj = 0;
            row.push_back(tempObj);
        }
        //put the row in the grid.
        grid.push_back(row);
    }

    file.close();


}


void printObjs(){
    for(int i =0; i < grid.size(); i++){
        for(int j =0; j< row.size(); j++){
            if(grid[i][j].Obj == ""){
                //cout << "nothing in this element" << endl;
            } else {
                cout << grid[i][j].Obj;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please comment on why before you downvote.

Comment: I have no idea how to structure this question because it is not a normal error

Comment: I realize this question is old, but what you've actually read into memory is an XPC message sent from System Preferences to the `cfprefs` daemon — dispatched when a setting is changed. From this, I'd guess that you read the wrong memory address, or allocated memory without clearing it with `memset()`.

Answer (score 1):

In `printObjs()` you are limiting the loop index `j` with `row.rize()`:

```
for(int j =0; j< row.size(); j++)
```

but use it to index into `grid` with `grid[i][j].Obj`. There is no reason that the size of `row` should be equal to that of `grid[i]`. Therefore you probably are accessing out-of-bounds causing undefined behavior.

It should probably be `for(int j =0; j< grid[i].size(); j++)` instead.

You also shouldn't be using global variables if it is not necessary. Both `tmpObj` and `row` are only used in `load`. Therefore declare them there.

Similarly `grid` can be a local variable, passed around between the functions.

Comment: Another issue is that `row` is never cleared, so it grows and grows as the program runs. More reason to stick with local variables and minimum scope.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Ah yes, didn't notice it, but that's exactly why it shouldn't be global. Clearing is easy to forget.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of problems in your code. Firstly:

```
while (getline(file, line)) {
    istringstream ss(line);
    while (getline(ss, zeroOrOne, ',')) {
        tempObj.Obj = zeroOrOne;
        tempObj.numItemsInObj = 0;
        row.push_back(tempObj);
    }
    grid.push_back(row);
}
```

Notice what's happening. You read every number per single line, add it to `row` and then add `row` to `grid`. What happens when you read the *second* line? You read more numbers and add more numbers to `row`. Now your `row` contains numbers from *both* first *and* second lines. You want to **clear** the `row` after copying it to the next element in the `grid`, like so:

```
while (getline(file, line)) {
    istringstream ss(line);
    while (getline(ss, zeroOrOne, ',')) {
        tempObj.Obj = zeroOrOne;
        tempObj.numItemsInObj = 0;
        row.push_back(tempObj);
    }
    grid.push_back(row);
    row.clear();
    // ^ notice the clear() call here
}
```

There is also another issue. Here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < grid.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < row.size(); j++) {
        if (grid[i][j].Obj == "") {
            //cout << "nothing in this vector" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << grid[i][j].Obj;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

you don't want to check for `row.size()`. You want to operate on the `grid` and you want the length of the `i`th row of the grid. Simply change it to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < grid.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].size(); j++) {
        // notice the change here ^^^
        if (grid[i][j].Obj == "") {
            //cout << "nothing in this vector" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << grid[i][j].Obj;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that in your fix to the first problem, there is no need for `row` to be global. Scoping it inside the outer loop eliminates the need to clear and makes things nice and easy.